# Windows loses DNS and doesn't update

Tags: windows, dns

I am running my own DNS on my local router for some hostnames in my LAN.
The DNS is working but from time to time windows loses the resolving. If I access my NAS for instance it happens, that I can load it's web GUI at its LAN FQDN but after a few reloads, Chrome tells me that the hostname is not found. When I type nslookup  into cmd, I get a response from my router but pinging that hostname gives an error still that the name was not resolved. A few attempts later, I can ping again and also access the GUI of the NAS. Why does this happen and how can I tell Windows to either keep the resolving or ask the router again when a name is not found in cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear Windows DNS Server cache:

```
Dnscmd 127.0.0.1 /clearcache
```

Clear Windows DNS Client cache:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Comment: do I have to do that every time? Or can I have that persistent?

Comment: @JherekCarnelian At the time of error.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there a way to prevent this behaviour persistent?

Comment: @JherekCarnelian There are two different approaches. 1. Hard minimalism. DNS in text mode. Dynamic updates are disabled. Only ipv4. By reducing the number of components decreases the probability of system failure. 2. Maximum coverage and support services. For example 2, this approach: DDNS DHCP WINS, ipv4 and ipv6 DNS, DNS LLMNR, IPAM ... When the emphasis is on the fact that one of the possible ways of resolving the host will work.